# What is the complement to 'set' in EdgeOS? (How do I check a value in EdgeRouter?)

Tags: configuration, settings, ubiquiti, ubiquiti-edgerouter

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/670836/disable-edgerouter-lite-gui-on-dmz-interface) question discusses how to set the gui and ssh listening addresses in EdgeOS running on an EdgeRouter. I'd like to check my current configuration before making a change, as well as learn the syntax for checking other settings in the future.

Given this example...

```
configure
set service gui listen-address 10.0.0.1
set service ssh listen-address 10.0.0.1
commit
save
exit
```

... how would I check those values before setting them? I would think that the following would work...

```
configure
check service gui listen-address 10.0.0.1
check service ssh listen-address 10.0.0.1
exit
```

Running `help`, I see the following...

```
root@ubnt# help
GNU bash, version 4.1.0(2)-release (mipsel-unknown-linux-gnu)
These shell commands are defined internally.  Type `help' to see this list.
Type `help name' to find out more about the function `name'.
Use `info bash' to find out more about the shell in general.
Use `man -k' or `info' to find out more about commands not in this list.

A star (*) next to a name means that the command is disabled.

 job_spec [&]                            if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif C>
 (( expression ))                        kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigs>
 . filename [arguments]                  let arg [arg ...]
 :                                       local [option] name[=value] ...
 [ arg... ]                              logout [n]
 [[ expression ]]                        mapfile [-n count] [-O origin] [-s c>
 alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]          popd [-n] [+N | -N]
 bind [-lpvsPVS] [-m keymap] [-f filen>  printf [-v var] format [arguments]
 break [n]                               pushd [-n] [+N | -N | dir]
 builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]       pwd [-LP]
 caller [expr]                           read [-ers] [-a array] [-d delim] [->
 case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...)>  readarray [-n count] [-O origin] [-s>
 cd [-L|-P] [dir]                        readonly [-af] [name[=value] ...] or>
 command [-pVv] command [arg ...]        return [n]
 compgen [-abcdefuv] [-o option]  >  select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMM>
 complete [-abcdefuv] [-pr] [-DE] >  set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option>
 compopt [-o|+o option] [-DE] [name ..>  shift [n]
 continue [n]                            shopt [-pqsu] [-o] [optname ...]
 coproc [NAME] command [redirections]    source filename [arguments]
 declare [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] [name[=val>  test [expr]
 dirs [-clpv] [+N] [-N]                  time [-p] pipeline
 echo [-neE] [arg ...]                   times
 enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [na>  trap [-lp] [[arg] signal_spec ...]
 eval [arg ...]                          true
 exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [argume>  type [-afptP] name [name ...]
 exit [n]                                typeset [-aAfFilrtux] [-p] name[=val>
 export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or ex>  ulimit [-SHacdefilmnpqrstuvx] [limit>
 false                                   umask [-p] [-S] [mode]
 fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last] o>  unalias [-a] name [name ...]
 for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMAND>  unset [-f] [-v] [name ...]
 for (( exp1; exp2; exp3 )); do COMMAN>  until COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 function name { COMMANDS ; } or name >  variables - Names and meanings of so>
 getopts optstring name [arg]            wait [pid]
 hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name >  while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
 help [-dms] [pattern ...]               { COMMANDS ; }
 history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or histo>
```

... and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> gets me this...

```
[edit]
root@ubnt#
comment         copy            load            run
commit          delete          loadkey         save
commit-confirm  discard         merge           set
compare         edit            rename          show
confirm         exit            rollback
[edit]
root@ubnt#
```

What am I missing? Should I use `show` instead of `set`? (And tab-complete my way to the variable in question?)

Comment: To complete the details here, I had some confusion about `commit` and `save` ... [this](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/EdgeOS-CLI-Primer-part-1/td-p/285388) tutorial answered those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `show`, and more to it, you could see an entire picture for a config section with it (or even complete configuration, if issued without parameters), not just particular value:

```
admin@maya:~$ configure
[edit]
admin@maya# show service dns
 forwarding {
     cache-size 150
     listen-on eth0
     listen-on eth0.10
 }
[edit]
admin@maya# show service d
dhcp-server  dns
[edit]
admin@maya# show service dns forwarding cache-size
 cache-size 150
[edit]
```